# UIButton not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, masonry

I use the following code to add a UIButton and a UITableView to a UIViewController:

```
    self.tableView = ({
        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView;
    });

    self.refreshButton = ({
        UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [button setTitle:@"testtest" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(clickRefreshButton)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        button.alpha = 1.0;
        button;
    });

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.refreshButton];
    CGFloat tableViewUpPadding = 20.0f;
    CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat buttonOffset = 10.0f;
    CGFloat buttonSideLength = 50.0f;

    [self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).offset(tableViewUpPadding);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-tabBarHeight);
        make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
    }];

    [self.refreshButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right).offset(-buttonOffset);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-buttonOffset);
        make.width.equalTo(@(buttonSideLength));
        make.height.equalTo(@(buttonSideLength));
    }];
```

Among which I use masonry to do auto-layout. However when I run the app the button doesn't appear, and not even in view debugging area.. Can somebody tell me why?

Or if I use strings and struts to create button, it still won't show :(

```
CGRect applicationFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(applicationFrame);
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(applicationFrame);
CGFloat buttonWidth = 40.0f;
CGFloat buttonHeight = 40.0f;
CGFloat spacing = 10.0f;
CGFloat buttonX = screenWidth - buttonWidth - spacing;
CGFloat buttonY = screenHeight - buttonHeight - spacing;
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
[self.refreshButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
```

By the way, I found that if I want to change `self.tableView`'s width using auto-layout, it's also impossible:

```
    [self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).offset(tableViewUpPadding);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom).offset(-tabBarHeight);
        make.width.equalTo(self.view.as_width).offset(-offset);
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
    }];
```

It turns out that the tableview is still as wide as self.view

Comment: where do u put this code ?

Comment: try in view will appear/did appear

Comment: then the autolayout might be doing wrong...try removing the masonry stuff and see if the button is added to view or not!

Comment: Yeah I've tried using strings and struts but still nothing shows :(

Comment: i forgot to notice that you didnt set the button frame. Set the button frame to something

Comment: I am using auto-layout so it's okay if I don't set its frame. See my updated question please.